# How can I display my multipages project using PHP?

Tags: php, display

I'm starting with PHP and have trouble displaying a multiple pages project. Is there a command line on Windows to display the main page ?

I'm using on command lines :
$ pwd
$ php -S 0.0.0.0:8080 -t public
[Mon Sep 20 06:36:47 2021] PHP 7.4.19 Development Server (http://0.0.0.0:8080) started

I understand that the main page of my website should be displayed on http://0.0.0:8080 but it doesn't work and every time I'm trying to display a website using php I do have this display.

Thanks for your help!

[php display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNRuA.png)

Comment: You need a index.html to show.

Comment: Try with `-t public/`